# Remove dither from gif on gifsicle

Tags: 14.04, command-line, gif

I'm sorry if my question can be silly, but I need you. How can I remove (if it's possible..) the dither from my gif using gifsicle? I searched but I didn't find anything (or I didn't understand.. I'm italian I may didn't search well). Thanks

Comment: Usually, dither is something you apply purposely on an image to compensate loss of information when you remove colours. This is something `gifsicle` can do. If I understand correctly, you are asking for the converse operation, roll back changes applied by a dithering algorithm. This is not impossible to do, but requires the exact knowledge of the dithering algorithm applied. `gifsicle` is not able to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, dither is something you apply purposely on an image to compensate loss of information when you remove colours. This is something [`gifsicle` can do](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/gifsicle.1.html):

> **`--dither`**
>
> This  option  only  matters  if  the  colormap  was  changed. With
>               `--dither`  on,  Floyd-Steinberg  error   diffusion   is   used   to
>               approximate  any  colors that were removed. This looks better, but
>               makes bigger files and can cause animation artifacts, so it is off
>               by default.

But if I understand correctly, you are asking for the converse operation, rolling back changes applied by a dithering algorithm. This is not impossible to do, but requires the exact knowledge of the dithering algorithm applied. `gifsicle` is naturally not able to do it.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: if this answers your question, don't forget to click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means "yes, this answer is valid"!